# How to add cordova AppRate plugin to Intel XDK?

Tags: cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I have added the plugin but cannot to setup config file(intelxdk.config.additions.xml).

If I add this code to config:

```
var customLocale = {} 
customLocale.title = "Rate %@";
customLocale.message = "If you enjoy using %@, would you mind taking a moment to rate it? It won’t take more than a minute. Thanks for your support!";
customLocale.cancelButtonLabel = "No, Thanks";
customLocale.laterButtonLabel = "Remind Me Later";
customLocale.rateButtonLabel = "Rate It Now";

AppRate.preferences.openStoreInApp = true;
AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL.android = 'market://details?id=com.site.test';
AppRate.preferences.customLocale = customLocale;
AppRate.preferences.displayAppName = 'My custom app title';
AppRate.preferences.usesUntilPrompt = 1;
AppRate.preferences.promptAgainForEachNewVersion = false;
AppRate.promptForRating(true);
```

nothing happing when I test my app on real device.

Answer (score 0):

First off, go to the project tab. 
           Go in plugins->
           Third party plugins. 
           Click on Get Plugin from the web.

For the name, write AppRate or anything you whant. For the plugin Id, write org.pushandplay.cordova.apprate and check "Plugin is located in the Apache Cordova plugins Registry".

BE WARNED that any third plugins can only be tested on the build tab.
After all that it should work.

P.S, there is nothing to add in the additions.xml file to make it work. Just put your code in a function that you call and it should work like a charm